# Strange traceroute to msdn.microsoft.com

Tags: networking, traceroute

The problem is I could not view any msdn.microsoft.com/*  site and the main site itself on my Ubuntu box on Google Chrome browser. Error is:

```
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.
```

When I run traceout I get different result:

Here is simple one:

```
traceroute msdn.microsoft.com
traceroute to msdn.microsoft.com (65.55.11.235), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  10.0.0.138 (10.0.0.138)  0.121 ms  0.131 ms  0.128 ms
2  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  1.730 ms  1.724 ms  2.024 ms
3  bzq-179-37-1.static.bezeqint.net (212.179.37.1)  18.314 ms  19.277 ms  20.694 ms
4  bzq-218-227-250.red.bezeqint.net (81.218.227.250)  22.806 ms  23.651 ms  24.820 ms
5  bzq-179-75-198.static.bezeqint.net (212.179.75.198)  26.650 ms  27.533 ms  28.791 ms
6  * * *
7  bzq-179-124-122.static.bezeqint.net (212.179.124.122)  76.032 ms  72.968 ms  74.660 ms
8  igblmdistc7504.uk.msft.net (195.66.224.140)  75.708 ms  76.797 ms  78.257 ms
9  ge-5-1-0-0.lts-64cb-1a.ntwk.msn.net (207.46.42.227)  80.125 ms  81.336 ms  82.671 ms
10  ge-7-0-0-0.nyc-64cb-1a.ntwk.msn.net (207.46.47.20)  179.232 ms so-7-1-0-0.ash-64cb-1b.ntwk.msn.net  (213.199.144.158)  162.508 ms  163.223 ms
11  xe-0-0-1-0.co1-96c-1b.ntwk.msn.net (207.46.45.29)  227.964 ms ge-7-0-0-0.co1-64c-1b.ntwk.msn.net (207.46.40.90)  228.226 ms xe-0-0-1-0.co1-96c-1b.ntwk.msn.net (207.46.45.29)  212.781 ms
12  10.22.8.54 (10.22.8.54)  215.046 ms xe-5-2-0-0.co1-96c-1a.ntwk.msn.net (207.46.40.167)  214.825 ms 10.22.8.58 (10.22.8.58)  213.251 ms
13  10.22.8.62 (10.22.8.62)  212.745 ms  213.827 ms 10.22.8.50 (10.22.8.50)  215.655 ms
14  10.22.8.62 (10.22.8.62)  211.665 ms !X 10.22.8.50 (10.22.8.50)  214.491 ms !X 10.22.8.54 (10.22.8.54)  218.471 ms !X
```

Line 1,2 : It's me

Line from 3-7: It's my Internet provider

Line 8 and on: I think I hit MS servers

**WTF line 12-14 ?????  10.22.8.x ????**

then I run this traceroute:

```
sudo traceroute -T msdn.microsoft.com
traceroute to msdn.microsoft.com (65.55.11.235), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  10.0.0.138 (10.0.0.138)  0.109 ms  0.127 ms *
2  * * *
3  * * *
4  * * *
5  * * *
6  * 65.55.11.235 (65.55.11.235)  16.019 ms  17.364 ms
```

So I hit MSDN web site already at 6 hop ! WTF ???

This is host -a msdn.microsoft.com from me:

```
host -a msdn.microsoft.com
Trying "msdn.microsoft.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19522
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;msdn.microsoft.com.        IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
msdn.microsoft.com. 3274    IN  CNAME   msdn.microsoft.akadns.net.
msdn.microsoft.akadns.net. 600  IN  A   65.55.11.235

Received 91 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53 in 108 ms
```

Could someone help me understand and fix it ??